# Is it possible to scrape contents of a GridView control in another .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, accessibility

Developing a specialized screen recorder application to grab data where there should be API's and there are not; I have gotten to the point where I can record button clicks and basic control contents (textboxes, labels, radio buttons, and so forth) using the Win32 API's.

Now, there is a special situation involving `GridView` and `ListView` (details view) controls in a .NET WinForms app. These are populated with data that scrolls beyond the visibility of the scroll bar.

If I can identify the type of control, is there a way to scrape its data, perhaps through Accessibility or something better?

Comment: You are looking for [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: That's fantastic... add an answer and I'll +1 that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All standard Windows control implement the interfaces required for [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). UI Automation allows to control a UI or query a UI for structure and content.

The [Content View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741931.aspx) is a subset of the control view. It contains UI items that convey the true information in a user interface, including UI items that can receive keyboard focus and some text that is not a label on a UI item. For example, the values in a drop-down combo box will appear in the content view.

The Content View is available by searching for elements that have the [`IsContentElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.iscontrolelement.aspx) property set to `true`, or by using the [`ContentViewWalker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.treewalker.contentviewwalker.aspx) to navigate the tree.